# how to pick only time in from WhDateTimePicker?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii

how to split time picker from this code? this contains date and time picker. i want to split the time.

enter code here

```
<fieldset>
<div id="dateTime" >
<?php
$StartDate = $this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.datetimepicker.WhDateTimePicker', array(
'model' => $model,
'name' => 'Start',
'attribute' => 'Start',
'pluginOptions' => array(
'pickTime' => true,                        
'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm PP',
'pick12HourFormat' => true,enter code here
'autoClose' => true,
),
'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Select date','autoClose' => true),                    
), true);
?>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `pickDate:` option in pluginOptions to be passed to datetimepicker plugin

```
pickDate: true, disables the date picker
pickTime: true, disables de time picker
```

Ref: http://yiiwheels.2amigos.us/api/class-WhDateTimePicker.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `format` from

```
'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm PP',
```

to

```
'format' => 'HH:mm PP',
```